# Using Block WIth System.Drawing.Graphics

Tags: system.drawing

I was wondering if the following code block is safe, meaning will the gfx dispose itself is something goes wrong?

```
Using gfx As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(img)
    gfx.Clear(Color.Transparent)
    gfx.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality
End Using
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's the whole point of the `using` keyword. From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> A Using block guarantees the disposal
>   of one or more such resources when
>   your code is finished with them. This
>   makes them available for other code to
>   use.

Comment: Thanks wanted to sure this was also true Graphics objects.